# Rank of Linear map of left multiplication by matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix. $F$ is the linear map $X\mapsto  AX$ where $X$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$

What is the rank of $F$?

Comment: what is rank of a linear map... can you give a definition?

Comment: Is $X$ is vector or a matrix?

Comment: X is a vector, just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear map associated with an invertible matrix must have rank $n$. If a map is invertible, then it is a bijection, so it is surjective onto $\mathbb R^n$ (or whatever field you're working in). The rank of the map is the dimension of the image, so it is $n$.

Comment: Thanks, is it ok if you could provide a brief explanation for why the rank is $n$?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda: This is not correct unless you specify the domain. Please see my answer

Comment: @PVanchinathan I'm pretty sure $X$ is intended to be a vector in $\mathbb R^n$? This seems to be a post from a first course in introductory linear algebra. OP, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes $X$ is a vector in $R^n$ and this is a first course in linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what the domain of your map is: that is what kind of matrices these $X$ are. Let me assume the domain to be the vector space $V$ of $n\times m$ matrices for some $m$. Then identity map of $V$ is of rank $nm$. (because its range is whole of $V$) If $A$ is $n\times n$ identity matrix  then the map you describe has rank $nm$. This argument holds for any non-singular $A$ too.